# When is $\min_{x\in X,y\in Y}f(x,y)=\min_{x\in X}(\min_{y\in Y}f(x,y))$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

When is

$$
\min_{x\in X,y\in Y}f(x,y)=\min_{x\in X}(\min_{y\in Y}f(x,y))?
$$

Comment: Are these $\min$'s or $\inf$'s? (not certain it will change the answer, but if $\min$'s (i.e., the minimum has to be actually reached for some value $(x,y)$, as is the case in particular when $X$ and $Y$ are finite), I would venture they are the same no matter what $f$ is.

Comment: @ClementC. I guess this is ment for $f(X,Y)$ to be a compact set (closed and bounded). So using $\min$ should be ok.

Comment: $f$ is then assumed to be continuous?

Comment: @ClementC. do you have any counterexample in mind such that the relation doesnt hold? given that min always exists?

Comment: Not really — trying to think if there could be such cases, actually. But I am not clear on whether the OP's question is on the assumptions on $f$, or on $X,Y$, or on both.

Comment: Hi everyone. I have noty made any particular assumptions on $X$, $Y$ or $f$. However, all I need is an existence result of the form: if $X$ is...... and $f$ is ..... then the relation holds.

Comment: @SuperM Maybe you could change your $\min$ into $\inf$, so that the answers stays concentrate on the separability of $f$ on $X \times Y$. You can then always state that these $\min$ exists and get a similar result.

Comment: To support my last comment, see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18605/max-and-min-versus-sup-and-inf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$, and let us prove that
$$\inf_{(x,y)\in X \times Y}f(x,y) = \inf_{x \in X}\left( \inf_{y \in Y}f(x,y)\right).$$
Therefore by [definition of the infimum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Formal_definition_2) we have a sequence $(x_n) \subset X$ such that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\inf_{y \in Y} f(x_n,y)\right) =\inf_{x\in X}\left( \inf_{y \in Y} f(x,y)\right),$$
furthermore for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is some sequence $(y_m^n) \subset Y$ such that 
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} f(x_n,y^n_m) = \inf_{y \in Y} f(x_n,y).$$
Now, note that $$f(x_n,y_m^n) \geq \inf_{(x,y)\in X \times Y}f(x,y)$$ for every $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and thus
$$ \inf_{x \in X} \left(\inf_{y\in Y}f(x,y)\right) =\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\lim_{m \to \infty}f(x_n,y^n_m)\right) \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \lim_{m \to \infty} \inf_{(x,y)\in X\times Y}f(x,y) \right) = \inf_{(x,y)\in X \times Y}f(x,y).$$
Still using the definition of the infimum, we have the existence of a sequence $(x_k,y_k) \subset X \times Y$ such that
$$ \inf_{(x,y)\in X \times Y}f(x,y) =\lim_{k \to \infty}f(x_k,y_k),$$
but note that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have
$$f(x_k,y_k) \geq \inf_{y \in Y}f(x_k,y) \geq \inf_{x \in X} \left( \inf_{y \in Y}f(x,y)\right).$$
It finally follows that
$$\inf_{(x,y)\in X \times Y}f(x,y) = \lim_{k \to \infty}f(x_k,y_k) \geq \lim_{k \to \infty}\inf_{x \in X}\left( \inf_{y \in Y}f(x,y)\right)=\inf_{x \in X}\left( \inf_{y \in Y}f(x,y)\right),$$
which proves the first statement. Now, if for every $z \in X$, $\min_{(x,y)\in X \times Y}f(x,y), \min_{y \in Y}f(z,y)$ and $\min_{x\in X} \left( \min_{y\in Y} f(x,y)\right)$ exist, $$\min_{(x,y)\in X \times Y}f(x,y)= \inf_{(x,y)\in X \times Y}f(x,y), \\ \min_{y \in Y}f(z,y)=\inf_{y \in Y}f(z,y),\\ \min_{x\in X} \left( \min_{y\in Y} f(x,y)\right)=\inf_{x\in X} \left( \inf_{y\in Y} f(x,y)\right)$$ 
and your result follows directly.

Comment: Thanks @Surb....I see the result holds all the time for inf, but when is it true for min?

Comment: @SuperM It is always true for min provided that they exists. Basically, each time you can prove that one of these minimum exists, you may turn the corresponding $\inf$ in a $\min$. I hope it is more clear to you... Anyway you should maybe have a look at the link I posted in the OP problem to get a better understanding of the difference between min and inf.

Comment: Ok...I see...Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SuperM Thank you for this very interesting question :).

Answer (score 1):

This equation is always true.

You proof this by contradiction:

1) It is clear that $$\min_{x\in X,y\in Y}f(x,y)>\min_{x\in X}(\min_{y\in Y}f(x,y))$$
cannot hold true.

2) Let us assume $$\min_{x\in X,y\in Y}f(x,y)<\min_{x\in X}(\min_{y\in Y}f(x,y))$$
 and let $x^\star $ and $y^\star $ minimizer.

Now, suppose you search over all possible $x$ for the smallest value of $\min_{y\in Y}f(x,y))$ and suppose that for each $x$ you can find the optimal $y$.

Then, choosing $x^\star$ will give you $y^\star$ and you arrive at $\min_{x\in X,y\in Y}f(x,y)$

As 1) and 2) cannot be true, you can conclude that equality holds always.

Comment: your proof supposes that for each x you can find the optimal y. What if that is not true?

Comment: For the proof it is enough that the optimal $y$ and $\min_{y\in Y}f(x,y))$ exist. But this is true by definition.