# Why the supremum of a closed set is not necessarily equal to the maximum?

Tags: general-topology, supremum-and-infimum

Consider a partially ordered set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$. I know that if $A$ is compact then $\sup A=\max A$. Could you give an intuition of why having $A$ closed is not enough to conclude $\sup A=\max A$? Assume that I allow the supremum to take an infinite value.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160451/difference-between-supremum-and-maximum) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18605/max-and-min-versus-sup-and-inf) might help you if you haven't already seen them.

Comment: What do those terms even mean for a set without an order?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ok thank you, I have added "partially ordered".

Comment: @NobleMushtak I still don't get why closeness is not enough

Comment: With what order?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks. Is specifying the order necessary to answer my question? Why?

Comment: Because the existence of either sup or max depends on the ordering.

Comment: Ok, thank you. If possible, could you suggest an ordering that would guarantee the existence of the sup?

Comment: Sure, pick the reverse of a well-order. Then any non-empty set will have a largest element, which will also be the sup. This will of course be a completely weird ordering.

Comment: $\sup(A)$ need not exist. If $A$ has a $\sup(A)$ and $\sup(A)$ is actually a member of the ordered set (so infinity(as a point not in the set above all points) is not allowed, because infinity can never be a maximum!) and $A$ is closed in the order topology, then $\sup(A) \in A$ and so $\sup(A) = \max(A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(X,<)$ is a linear order in the order topology and for some $A\subseteq X$, $A$ is closed and $\alpha=\sup(A)$ exists but it is not an element of $A$. Then, for every open interval $I$ containing $\alpha$ then by definition of supremum, there is an element $a\in A$ such that $a\in I$.

This shows that $\alpha$ is a limit point of $A$, and since $A$ is closed it should contain all its limit points, so $\alpha\in A$, and $\sup A=\max A$. I believe then that when considering the order topology it is the case that if $A$ is closed and $\sup A$ exists, $\sup A=\max A$. It could happen however that a closed set does not have maximum nor supremum, as for instance $A=[0,\infty)$ in the reals.

However, with a change of topology we might have different things. Consider the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ whose basic opens are sets of the form $[a,b)$. In this case, the set $A=(-\infty,0)$ is closed, does not have a maximum and $\sup A=0$ exists.

Comment: What do you mean by the logic topology?

Comment: That is just a bad habit. I meant in the order topology.