# Why A is closed in M does not imply A has maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

After I wrote this question, many people commented that maximum needs to be defined with a metric space and a relevant norm. Let me just simplify my question as only in $\Bbb R^1$:

> > For a set $A \subseteq\,\Bbb R^1$, in a euclidean metric,
> >
> > $m = \max(A)$ when $m\in A, \forall x\in A, x \le m$

I know that the following claim is true:

> > A is compact $\to\;\exists\,\max$(A), and $\sup(A) = \max(A)$

Why is the following claim not true? (The claim is fixed again. I am so sorry)

> > For A$\subseteq\Bbb R^1$
> >
> > A is closed in $\Bbb R^1 \;\land\; \exists\,\sup (A) \to\;  \sup$(A) = $\max$(A)

I tried to find [already existing questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1754058/465004) but could find only one, which does provide a sufficient answer.

Comment: Is it not possible for a set to be both closed an unbounded?  In $\mathbb{R}$, you might want to consider intervals of the form $[a,\infty)$.  Or even just consider the entire space $M$, which is both open *and* closed (clopen!).

Comment: What is $\max(A)$ in a metric space?

Comment: I am sorry, I realized I made a mistake in my question. I am fixing the question now.

Comment: I fixed the question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @acubens555 You did not answer my question: what is $\max(A)$ in a metric space?

Comment: @acubens555, if you do not tell us what you mean by $\max(A)$ when $A$ is a subset of a metric space, your question is impossible to answer — usually, that does not mean anything.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Max(A)=m where ($\exists m\in A, \forall x\in A, x \le m$)

Comment: @acubens555 Then please tell me what does $x\ge m$ mean in a metric space.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos x is smaller than m. Is it only possible in $\Bbb R^1$ ?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I am sorry for my defective question. I am trying to answer your questions. I have only learned introductory real analysis, so I do not know much.

Comment: A metric is not enough to define a maximum element.  You need something more, i.e. some way of determining the *size* of an element.  That is, you need a norm.  In order to say what the "maximal element of $A$" is, you have to define a norm.  The metric doesn't do that for you.

Comment: Your new edit doesn't answer the question---what does it mean for $x \le m$?  The complex plane is a metric space, but which is larger:  $i$ or $1$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for your comments. I fixed it again. Lets only confine to Real numbers with Euclidean metric.

Comment: Ever closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a maximal element, and that maximum is equal to the supremum (indeed, any time a set has a maximal element, that maximal element must also be the supremal element).

Comment: Under the definitions in your question, what is, for example $\max([1,+\infty))$?

Comment: @tilper in that case, maximum does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be closed, and suppose that $-\infty < \sup(A) = \alpha < \infty$.  By definition of the supremum, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is some $x_n \in A$ such that
$$ \alpha - x_n = |\alpha - x_n| < \frac{1}{n}.$$
But then $x_n$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ that converges to $\alpha$.  This implies that $\alpha$ is a limit point of $A$.  As $A$ is closed, it contains all of its limit points, therefore $\alpha \in A$.  But then we have
$$ \alpha \in A \qquad\text{and}\qquad \alpha \ge x\, \forall x\in A. $$
Therefore $\alpha = \max(A)$.

Comment: I can understand your answer. The existence of sup(A) implies A is bounded above. Since A is closed, sup(A) is also the element of A. So max(A)=sup(A).

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Comment: Then in what cases A being closed in M is not enough to guarantee sup(A)=max(A) ? I can understand if M = $\Bbb R^1$, than sup(A)=max(A) is guaranteed.

Comment: The supremum is always defined, but need not be finite.  The set $[a,\infty)$ is closed, but not bounded.  This set has no maximum, but $\sup[a,\infty) = \infty$ is perfectly well defined.

Comment: Does [a,$\infty$) have supremum? I have never heard about this... Thanks for your teaching.

Comment: So your example of [a,$\infty$) is an example that the following claim is wrong. I am right?   For A$\subseteq\Bbb R^1$, A is closed in $\Bbb R^1 \;\land\; \exists\,\sup (A) \to\; \exists\,\max(A) \land\, \max$(A)=$\sup$(A)

Comment: Oh I fixed...Too many obvious mistakes today...

Comment: Every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a supremum.  The important point is that the supremum is *finite*, i.e. the set is bounded.  The correct formulation of the theorem is:  if $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed and bounded (bounded means that $\sup(A) < \infty$), then $A$ has a maximum, and $\max(A) = \sup(A)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I can now understand all of my questions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you need to add A is non-empty, since empty set is closed and bounded, but does not have the supremum.

Comment: $\sup(\emptyset) = -\infty$, thus the empty set is not bounded.

Comment: A professor in U-Wisconsin Madison at math department confirmed me that empty set does not have the supremum. I am not sure who is right.

Comment: Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$.  It is vacuously true that if $x\in\emptyset$, then $x \le -\infty < a$.  Therefore $\sup(\emptyset) < a$.  As this holds for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $\sup(\emptyset) = -\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. I will ask your claim to the professor. I am confused. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

For *every* subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ (closed or not), if $\max(A)$ exists, then it is equal to $\sup(A)$. In fact, if $m=\max(A)$ then $(\forall a\in A):a\leqslant m$, and therefore $m$ is an upper bound of $A$. Furthermore, if $m'<m$ then there is an element of $A$ which is greater than $m'$, namely $m$. So, $m$ is the least upper bound of $A$, which means that $m=\sup(A)$.

What made you think that this was not true?

Comment: Oh... my god.. I did mistake. I am so sorry for many mistakes. Let me fix my question again as below: A is closed in $\Bbb R^1 \;\land\; \exists\,\sup (A) \to\; \exists\,\max(A) \land\, \max$(A)=$\sup$(A)